# Should λ-terms all be easily translated back into natural language syntax?

Tags: syntax, english, formal-semantics, lambda-calculus

We have encountered this question when we try to read Heim and Kratzer's book. This following picture is taken from Heim & Kratzer (1998: 40).

[image]

Our answers are simply based on the subscripts:

```
(a)  <<e,t>, <e,t>>
(b) <<e,<e,t>>, <e,t>>
(c) <e,<<e,t>, <e, t>>>
(d) <<e,t>,t>
(e) invalid?
(f) <<e,t>,<<e,t>,t>>
```

However, we could hardly translate those λ-calculus into natural language. Were formal semantics in general meant to be used for syntax-to-semantics mapping but not the other way around? See more comments in this [blog](https://xylhermine.wixsite.com/aasr/post/on-the-expressive-power-of-the-%CE%BB-calculus).

Any clarification or comments are welcome!

Comment: @Keelan I am not sure if I understand. Do you mean it is simply a unit of a constituent rather than a well formed phrase. So, for _a_, it actually denotes _gray_ in the constituent of _big gray cat_?

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment was a bit confused. I have written an answer that should be more helpful.

Comment: Millions of thanks! Keelan! I am starting to read the book and cannot believe that those questions embedded in the first few chapters have already indicated a lot of gems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) is the denotation for *gray* proposed in (11) on p. 66. Its type is *(et)et* so that when applied to *cat* with type *et* we get *gray cat* with type *et* as well.

In (b) we have a predicate *f* of which Ann is the subject but the object position is left unspecified, for example *Ann verbed ___*. The denotation is the set of entities which Ann verbed. It is thus somewhat like the passive predicate *was verbed by Ann*. Such an account of the passive is given by Dowty and briefly discussed by Heim & Kratzer in note 18 on pp. 59–60.

(c) is like (a), but *gray* has been replaced with *in y*, and *y* has been made an argument. It is the denotation for *in* on p. 66. If *in* is of type *e(et)et*, then *in the box* is of type *(et)et*, like *gray* above.

(d) is the denotation of *something* on p. 141.

Since *Mary* is type *e*, (e) is of type *(et)e*. We could imagine a determiner *actuallymary* which maps any NP to *Mary*: the denotation of *actuallymary cat* would be Mary (compare: *the cat* maps the predicate *cat* to a single entity). There must of course be a reason why such determiners do not exist. H&K suggest that this is a syntactic constraint rather than a semantic one (see pp. 126–127). In the semantic system, the formula is well-formed and has meaning, but you would not use it as the denotation for any expression in natural language.

(f) is the denotation of the quantifier *no* on p. 146.

Comment: Thanks very much Keelan!  Very detailed and informative answer! Many thanks for providing extra notes on the page of the book. Heim & Kratzer's book is super technical and requires a lot of familiarities on the functions.

Comment: @Xia.Yili no problem. Of course it’s fine to take the question at this point just as an exercise in understanding the technical machinery, without translating them to natural language. But it’s fun to do so nevertheless :)

Comment: Why do you assume that *Mary* is of type et, and not e?

Comment: @NatalieClarius Thanks, corrected.

Comment: I was confused too. Thanks for pointing it out.